# Swift generics, cannot infer type T

Tags: swift, generics

I've tried a bunch of different things but i'm not good at generics.
How do I call a function with a variable that needs to be both a solid type like `UIViewController`, as well as conforming to a protocol like `NavBarResponder` ?
Thanks!

```
weak var lastNavBarResponder: UIViewController?

func reloadExtendedNavBar() {
    self.updateState()
    self.updateStatusBadges()
    if let vc = self.lastNavBarResponder {
        self.setup(viewController: vc) // Error: Generic parameter T cannot be inferred
    }
}

func setup<T: UIViewController>(viewController: T) where T: NavBarResponder {
...
```

Comment: Which Swift version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error is because `UIViewController` doesn't naturally conform to `NavBarResponder`, so the compiler can't guarantee that `lastNavBarResponder` fits the requirements of `setup`.

Try changing `lastNavBarResponder` to be of a type that is a `UIViewController` that conforms to the `NavBarResponder` protocol.

Here is a self-contained example showing how this would be implemented.

```
protocol NavBarResponder {}

class NavBarResponderController: UIViewController {}
extension NavBarResponderController: NavBarResponder {}

var lastNavBarResponder: NavBarResponderController? = NavBarResponderController()

func setup<T: UIViewController>(viewController: T) where T: NavBarResponder {
    print("Works")
}

func reloadExtendedNavBar() {

    if let vc = lastNavBarResponder {
        setup(viewController: vc) 
    }
}

reloadExtendedNavBar()
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I tried this, but now it seems I need to make every class that is currently a `UIViewController` conforming to `NavBarResponder` this new class, `NavBarResponderController`. Otherwise I cannot assign `lastNavBarResponder`. Is there another way?